# How does branch cut and branch point arise while taking partial trace of a subsystem?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, entropy, mathematical-physics, path-integral, complex-numbers

I am reading the paper on, "Entanglement Entropy and Quantum Field Theory"
[arXiv:hep-th/0405152](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0405152).

In this paper, the author introduces cut in the path integral which is referred to be the partial trace over space and it gives partial density matrix of a subsystem.

Does the partial density have a branch cut in general? Is it multivalued? This question arises because of the fact that while taking  Tr$[\rho^{n}]$ , the density matrix is called as Riemann surface with a cut on it as it is a partial trace. What is the origin of the multivaluedness to term density matrix as Riemann surface?

Comment: Can someone please help me in understanding this of branch cut in density matrix ?